# Colours disappear when exporting to Blend4Web

Tags: texturing, export, blend4web

I am a beginner with Blender. When I export the blender file to Blender4web file all colours are gone.

[image]

Comment: Your colors are not gone, either your textures are missing, or your materials are malformed. Whichever the case it is impossible to know with this little available info

Comment: Could you post the .blend? Without it everyone is just left guessing since we can't see your material settings or B4W settings.

Comment: Here is a folder with blend (smaug.blend) including also html file--> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5r93qw65he2UVU1bzJnMHZWaG8
Thank you for your time! :) @Mentalist

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5r93qw65he2YXV5RnBsckhZTTA  ---> here is a folder in .zip

Comment: Please simplify your file to the most minimal and compact solution that illustrates your problem, don't make users download multi-megabyte files of useless information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your .blend is using .tga and .tif files, which are [not supported in Blend4Web](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/textures.html#texture-types) (since they are not web-friendly formats).

If you convert these to .png (or .jpg where lossy is acceptable) you should be fine. This will also cut your file sizes down drastically and probably even improve your Viewport performance within Blender. Remember that since your delivery platform is a web browser, smaller and lower-res images are better whenever possible.

Another issue I noticed (unrelated to images) is that you'll need to either scale down your model or increase the clipping distance.

Comment: You were absolutely right! It works now, thank you. Also file size is smaller (50%). @Mentalist

Comment: Great, glad it's working for you! Since it seems this solved your problem, would you mind accepting the answer? Happy blending.